# PHP Array - Alternative output

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a simple array working based off the url ie www.example.com/apple/ it places in the apple text where I need it - but I also need an option of pasting in a separate fixed piece of text based off the brand.

IE so I can draw it with $brand_to_use to place in "apple" for example and $brandurl_to_use to draw in "apple.co.uk" where I need it but I'm not sure how to add this to the array based off the original brand.

Thanks

```
$recognised_brands = array( 
  "apple", 
  "orange", 
  "pear",
  // etc 
); 

$default_brand = $recognised_brands[0]; // defaults brand to apple

$brand_to_use = isset($_GET['brand']) && in_array($_GET['brand'], $recognised_brands) 
  ? $_GET['brand'] 
  : $default_brand;
```

Pseudo code update example:

```
recognised brands = 
apple
orange
pear

default brand = recognised brand 0


recognised brandurl =
apple = apple.co.uk
orange = orange.net
pear = pear.com



the brandurl is found from the recognised brands so that in the page content I can reference

brand which will show the text apple at certain places +
brandurl will show the correct brand url related to the brand ie apple.co.uk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your array as a key/value pair and search for a key in the array. The value part of each pair can be an object if you like.

```
$recognised_brands = array(  
  "apple" => "http://apple.co.uk/",  
  "orange" => "http://orange.co.uk/",  
  "pear" => "http://pear.co.uk/", 
  // etc  
);  

reset($recognised_brands);  // reset the internal pointer of the array
$brand = key($recognised_brands); // fetch the first key from the array

if (isset($_GET['brand'] && array_key_exists(strtolower($_GET['brand']), $recognised_brands))
    $brand = strtolower($_GET['brand']);

$brand_url = $recognised_brands[$brand];
```

Comment: It's worth noting here that array dereferencing (i.e. `array_keys($default_brand)[0]`) only works in 5.4 - which is exactly why I split that operation over two lines. The `array_keys()` approach is arguably better though as it doesn't affect the array pointer, although potentially must less memory efficient if `$recognised_brands` is very large. I think I shall award you +1 for a good working answer though.

Comment: Here you go: with `reset` and `key` offering you the fastest and most memory efficient solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you are wanting to do is something like this:

```
$recognised_brands = array( 
  "apple" => 'http://www.apple.co.uk/', 
  "orange" => 'http://www.orange.com/', 
  "pear" => 'http://pear.php.net/',
  // etc 
); 

$default_brand = each($recognised_brands);
$default_brand = $default_brand['key'];

$brand = isset($_GET['brand'], $recognised_brands[$_GET['brand']]) 
  ? $_GET['brand'] 
  : $default_brand;
$brand_url = $recognised_brands[$brand];
```

If you want to dynamically set the default brand to the first element of the array, it starts to get messy very quickly. But you can do something like this:

Comment: `in_array()` looks for a matching value, not a matching key

Comment: @WouterH Darnit, meant to change that to `isset()` and forgot. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to `reset()` before you do `each()` since you don't know the current position of the internal pointer.

Comment: I did set it up like "apple" => 'http://www.apple.co.uk/',  but doesnt that then only allow me to draw with $brand_to_use which will then for apple draw http://www.apple.co.uk ? I need to be able to pull both apple in some instances and then the http://www.apple.co.uk in others with something like $brand_to_use for apple and $brandurl_to_use for the apple url after brand is set - sorry for my confusion

Comment: @user1523591 Err... what? Sorry, can you illustrate this in code? I don't understand what you're asking there...

Comment: @user1523591: are you now asking to rename `$brand_url` to `$brandurl_to_use`? I don't understand. Can you edit your question and add what you really want in pseudo code or anything?

Comment: I'm sorry for being so useless at explaining this - literally a bodged week into PHP! I'm normally a video editor!

I've added a pseudo example - I just want 

www.example.com/apple

to be able to draw in the content the text "apple" in some places and then another piece of text based off the brand in this case a url "apple.co.uk" so that some div's and content text will show apple and others will modify links to show apple.co.uk all off the www.example.co.uk/apple variable

Comment: @user1523591 Both WouterH's code and mine do exactly that (although his is slightly better). After the code has executed, `$brand` will contain `apple` and `$brand_url` will contain `http://www.apple.co.uk/`. So when you want just `apple` you `echo $brand;` and when you want the full URL you `echo $brand_url;`

Comment: thanks so much for confirming that Dave, I couldn't read the code well enough to extract that information - I'll use WoutersH's as you suggest

thanks for your time and patience :)